# Using Redis for storing Sessions in Laravel 5.6 but facing browser issue

Tags: php, laravel, session, browser, redis

I am using `Redis` in `Laravel 5.6` for storing `Sessions` but its updating in all browsers like when I add `session_id` variable and sets its value in `Redis` then it not only assigned and displays in one browser but also to other.

Like if I assign some value to `Redis variable` in `Chrome browser` then it also shows in `Firefox browser` as well.

But I want to maintain separate Redis Session in separate browser like it happens with standard PHP Sessions.

Please check my below code where I assign the value to Redis `session_id` variable if its empty.

```
$session_id = Redis::get('session_id');
if(empty($session_id)){
     $session_id = str_random(40);
     Redis::set('session_id',$session_id);
}
```

Please help me to modify this code to make it browser specific. How do I assign the value to `Redis Session variable` that can be read by one browser only, not by other.

Hope someone can help me! Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, you shouldn't need to do this. Laravel handles the session management automatically, including creating session ID's.

Comment: I am using because client website is having lots of traffic and my server team recommends it as it can manage heavy traffic and faster then Laravel Sessions.

Comment: You can still use Redis as the store and have laravel manage the session transactions: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session

Redis
Before using Redis sessions with Laravel, you will need to install the predis/predis package (~1.0) via Composer. You may configure your Redis connections in the database configuration file. In the session configuration file, the connection option may be used to specify which Redis connection is used by the session.

Comment: Mike, thanks for your message but Redis is already working very fine. Only issue I am facing that it is updating in all the browsers but I want browser specific so that no other browser can get effected. It's like you login in one browser and in other browsers as well, you automatically logged in.

Comment: Hmm, very odd, I'll do a little more reading.